# Stacking toolbars in a multi-row taskbar in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, taskbar, toolbar

I have a high taskbar (two rows) in Windows Vista, and I want to stack toolbars (which tend to be designed to take up one row).  The default behavior is side-by-side only.

See image: top of image is default side-by-side toolbars, I would like to be able to locate the address toolbar under the media toolbar, for example, bottom of image.

[image: Stacking Toolbars]

Dragging the toolbars just swaps their horizontal position, they don't slide underneath each other.

Is this possible?  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats not possible, 
What is possible though, is have the quick lauch, address bar and the media toolbar in one row, and the top row for task bar